# How to remove "+00:00" from end of datetime.datetime object. (not remove time)

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, datetime, psycopg2

I'm calling a database, and returning a datetime.datetime object as the 3rd item in a tuple.

The SQL statement is: `SELECT name,name_text,time_received FROM {}.{} WHERE DATE(time_received)=CURRENT_DATE LIMIT 1`

If I do `print(mytuple[2])` it returns something like: `2017-05-31 17:21:19+00:00` but always with that "+00:00" at the end for every value. How do I remove that trailing "+00:00" from the datetime.datetime object?

I've tried different string-stripping methods like `print(mytuple[2][:-6])` but it gives me an error saying that datetime.datetime object is not subscriptable. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you could always format the output as part of the select. It appears it's including the timezone offset.  you simply need to exclude that from the render.  `to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS')` would be one way. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html gives a host of others. (done in the SELECT of the SQL statement to get mytuple[2]

Comment: @xQbert where does that `to_char` go if I'm selecting multiple columns, the others of which are not timestamps, but strings.

Comment: Post the SQL used to get your result set.  It should go around the timestamp column. which you can then alias back but it does depend on what data type you want back from the database as well.  if you want a date/time then we would need to convert it back to the appropriate datatype.

Comment: @xQbert I added my SQL statement. I'm taking the value and putting into a javascript DataTables column and sorting on it. I think datatables treats it as a string anyway? perhaps not, so maybe having a date/time is best

Comment: so `SELECT name,name_text,to_char(time_Received, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS)'...` time received (mytuple[2]) wouild then be formatted as character data instead of time.  So if you're program is handling it as a date,we'd have to convert it back to a date datatype.

Comment: @xQbert that all worked for me, thanks for your help. If you post as an answer I'd be happy to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)

`to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS')` would be one way.

For your specific case:

```
SELECT name,name_text,to_char(time_Received, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS')
```

Time received (mytuple[2]) would then be formatted as character data instead of time.

So if your program is handling it as a date, we'd have to convert it back to a date datatype

Answer (score 0):

I imagine in order to use string stripping methods, you must first convert it to a string, then strip it, then convert back to whatever format you want to use. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
from time import strftime
strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```